# is it possible to use windows 8 search charm in Winform application?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am developing a winform application in C# (.Net 4.5)for windows 8(not meant for Metro /RT). As far as I understand the Charms in windows 8(Search,Share, Setting) are not available for classic .net application but available only for metro style apps. Am I correct here? Please let me know if there is a way to access this charm in normal .Net 4.5 applications.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct, it can't be used by any none-metro application.